Why does shell come into python interpreter when executing GNU gdb
[root@localhost build]# gdb
 Python 3.11.6 (main, Nov  6 2024, 15:43:30) [GCC 12.3.1 (openEuler 12.3.1-37.oe2403)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

[root@localhost ~]# file /usr/libexec/gdb
/usr/libexec/gdb: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=1e7c77973d703cfceaf0c5fe593cdf208930d72f, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/gdbinit
# System-wide GDB initialization file.
python
import glob
# glob.iglob is not available in python-2.4 (RHEL-5).
for f in glob.glob('/etc/gdbinit.d/*.gdb'):
  gdb.execute('source %s' % f)
for f in glob.glob('/etc/gdbinit.d/*.py'):
  gdb.execute('source %s' % f)
end

/etc/gdbinit.d is empty.
Why does gdb enter python interpreter?
I confirm the gdb is the right GNU gdb.
